# XML and soapenv

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to create an xml ..
running the following code, the first doc is created ..
but the last line directly kill rstudio .. (R session aborted ..)

```
library(XML)
# CREATE XML FILE
doc = newXMLDoc()
root = newXMLNode("Envelope", doc = doc)

# WRITE XML NODES AND DATA
mvNode = newXMLNode("Header/",  parent = root)
mvNode = newXMLNode("Body",  parent = root)

print(doc)

# CREATE XML FILE
doc = newXMLDoc(namespaces = list("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"))
root = newXMLNode("soapenv:Envelope", doc = doc)

# WRITE XML NODES AND DATA
mvNode = newXMLNode("soapenv:Header", parent = root)
mvNode = newXMLNode("soapenv:Body",  parent = root)
```

Can someone confirm ? Can someone explain this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `fixNamespaces` argument, specifying `dummy=FALSE` to have child nodes use ancestor namespaces which appears to resolve this interesting issue (which also occurs in RGui).

Also, the `namespaces` argument (plural) in `newXMLDoc` does not appear to work with subsequent `newXMLNode`. Such an argument may relate to the nodes added within its method with `...` which I cannot get to work. Therefore define namespace at the root or highest needed level for namespace.

```r
# CREATE XML FILE
doc <- newXMLDoc()

root <- newXMLNode(
  "soap:Envelope", 
  doc = doc,
  namespace = c(soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"),
  fixNamespaces = c(dummy=FALSE, default=TRUE)
)

# WRITE XML NODES AND DATA
mvHeader <- newXMLNode(
  "soap:Header", parent = root, fixNamespaces = c(dummy=FALSE, default=TRUE)
)

mvBody <- newXMLNode(
  "soap:Body",  parent = root, fixNamespaces = c(dummy=FALSE, default=TRUE)
)

print(doc)
# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
#   <soap:Header/>
#   <soap:Body/>
# </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you deserve your name !